# PHP - Replace Letters in a String

Tags: php, str-replace

I am confused by str_replace.
Here is the thing: 
For example, I have a string:

```
$string = 'ababcd';
```

Then I want to replace all 'a' to 'b', all 'b' to 'c' and all 'c' to 'a'. My desired result is:

```
bcbcad
```

But my actual result is:

```
aaaaad
```

Here is my code:

```
$string='ababcd';
$string=str_replace(['a', 'b', 'c'], ['b', 'c', 'a'], $string);
echo $string;
```

Please help me!!!

Comment: That's what `strtr()` exists for (with string replacement lists, not arrays).

Comment: Thank u mario :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution for this issue:

```
$string = 'ababcd';
$string = strtr($string, 'abc', 'bca');
echo $string;
```

or:

```
$string = 'ababcd';
$string = strtr($string, ['a' => 'b', 'b' => 'c', 'c' => 'a']);
echo $string;
```